# plot a point in map using lat & long value in geotools

Tags: java, javafx, geotools

i have lat & long values in my code in the form of a list. its in decimal format. i am using geotools library in my java code. the following code is what i found to plot a point in a website.

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
featureBuilder.add(point);
```

this is the code i implemented

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(Long.get(0), Lat.get(0)));
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder();
```

But i can't perform it. its asking for a futuretype in SimpleFeatureBuilder(). can any one help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

GeoTools requires a "schema" or FeatureType that describes the feature you are trying to build. So you need to do something like:

```
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("Location",
            "the_geom:Point:srid=4326," + // <- the geometry attribute: Point type
            //"name:String," +   // <- a String attribute
            //"number:Integer"   // a number attribute
    );
```

You will certainly need the POINT line. and then will need to add more lines like the commented out ones if you decide to add some attributes to your point later.